# scraped data is decoded

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scraping the data form this link,
but I faced a problem the scraped content not completed or may be decoded:

```
import requests as requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests

linkScraping = 'https://olx.com.eg/ad/%D8%B4%D9%82%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3-ID197116204.html'
page = requests.get(linkScraping, timeout=100)

print(page.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(page.text)
```

**I expect the output of data:** it is the content of html with data in Arabic and English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpage that you are trying to scrape uses JavaScript to dynamically load data, which means that the data is not available in the page source when the page is initially loaded. Therefore, to scrape this data, you need to use a tool that can interact with the webpage in a browser context and wait for the JavaScript to execute and load the data like [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html)

we are also using [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) for chromdriver managemenet

In below code, Selenium web driver  is used to load the webpage and we wait for page load to complete with 15 sec sleep . It then extracts the page source and passes it to BeautifulSoup for parsing. The parsed data is printed to the console.

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = 'https://www.olx.com.eg/ad/%D8%B4%D9%82%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B9-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%AC%D9%86%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%B5%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%B9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B3-ID197116204.html'

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
# Waiting for page to loaf completely
time.sleep(15)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
print(soup.contents)
```

This will give you the complete html of the page now